# How to automatically use "From Text/CSV" when opening .csv file in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-explorer, csv, default-settings

When opening a CSV file in Excel the normal way it works *ok*, but the way it displays the data is lackluster. I recently discovered that under the "Data" tab there is a button "From Text/CSV". When you import a CSV file with this button it detects headers, data types (by *columns* instead of individual fields), column widths and offers much richer functionality like sorting and filtering.

This is what I want, but it takes much longer to open Excel, click this button and then select my file, instead of just double-clicking the file directly. How can I make the "From Text/CSV" button's functionality be the default way that Excel opens a .csv file directly from File Explorer?

Microsoft Excel for Office 365 MSO
Version 1808

Comment: Create a macro that runs the From Text/CSV function upon Workbook Load Event

Comment: Is [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1316138/how-do-i-set-the-default-data-type-to-text-while-importing-data-from-a-text-fi?rq=1) helping?